# Map integer to color in rainbow spectrum

Tags: c++, colors

I want to color **k** clusters of points in a 2D grid. Right now I using a naive approach.

I'm using RGB to set a color, the G component is fix, R is counted down gradually, B is counted up gradually. So the first cluster has R set to 255 and the last to 0, vice versa for B.

```
int r = 255, g = 80, b = 0;
// do stuff
int step = 255 / k;
// loop over data
int cluster = getCurrentCluster();
int currentR = r - (cluster * step);
int currentG = g;
int currentB = b + (cluster * step);
```

The current solution is working and effektive. It's possible to differentiate the clusters by colors

[image: colored voronoi cells that show result of cluster analysis with k-means clustering. K is set to 30, number of elements is 5M, image dimension is square with 1M pixels]

But I don't like it, and would prefer rainbow colors or at least a richer spectrum.

How can I achieve that? How can I map an integer in interval [0, k) to a color that meets my requirements?

Another approach that came to my mind was to map the integer to a wave length in a given interval, e.g. 400 nm to 800 nm (should roughly be the rainbow spectrum, if I recall correctly) and convert the wavelength to RGB.

Comment: What about 3 different noise functions for R, G and B?

Comment: I don't suppose the code is available somewhere for us to play with?

Comment: @TartanLlama Hmm, not sure. It's an assignment for an lecture, is also has components that run on the GPU. I'll ask if I can release it, maybe only the CPU stuff

Comment: @Brett Sry, could you elaborate more please? I don't quite understand how that would lead to a rainbow spectrum.

Comment: @mike sorry it wouldn't give a rainbow spectrum but it should at least give a richer spectrum as you would be generating values for all 3 color components

Comment: The problem with generating values for all 3 spectrums is that you can easily find yourself in the gray scale. That's why I had one value fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to map a linear range to a rainbow like spectrum then you are better off starting with a color space like HSV and then convert to RGB.

[Here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html) you find the details of the conversion

Comment: That's a great idea. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

HSV will give the nicest results, but needs trigonometry.

Instead, consider three functions:

1. R: `r = x < 256 ? 255 - x : x < 512 ? 0       : x - 512`
2. G: `g = x < 256 ? x       : x < 512 ? 512 - x : 0`
3. B: `b = x < 256 ? 0       : x < 512 ? x - 256 : 768 - x`

These may be easier and faster, although less aestethically pleasing (not so a nice yellow, orange, etc.)

Comment: What is x? And what is it domain?

Comment: This should be obvious from the functions.

Comment: So x equals cluster * steps, as I used it above

Comment: Not exactly the same as in your code, but almost. Also beware of integer division!